# SQL - how to let sql auto set the next id

Tags: sql, mysql, getlatest

how can I let sql/mysql set the next id, that I have no problems with posts at the same time?

Comment: Use AUTO_INCREMENT command....

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for.  Do you want to auto-increment a primary key, or get the last insert ID to use in your next insert?

Comment: Assuming you are referring to a table insert. Make the column in your table an IDENTITY column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255)
)
```

`Auto_Increment` can be used as ID as there wont any duplicate value.
When insert value for the table :

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName)
VALUES ('Hello','World')
```

The table will look like this.

```
ID | FirstName | LastName
1  |   Hello   |  World
```